# Intuitive meaning of Dot Product

Tags: vectors

I know intuitively that the Cross Product of two vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ represents another vector $\vec{A \times B}$ perpendicular to it. In study of physics we come across this situation a lot. Hence I can visualize some applications of it

[image: Cross Product]

I know that the dot product of two vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ is scalar quantity and also that it represents angular relationship between $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ .i.e.

- If $\vec{A}$.$\vec{B} = 0$. Then $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are perpendicular.
- If $\vec{A}$.$\vec{B} > 0$ (Positive). Then the angle between $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are less than $90^o$.
- If $\vec{A}$.$\vec{B} < 0$ (Negative). Then the angle between $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are greater than $90^o$.

But I won't be able to understand intuitively, What does the dot product represents. What does the magnitude of the dot product of two vectors represents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the physical significance of dot & cross product of vectors? Why is division not defined for vectors?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14082/)

Comment: @KyleKanos I've already read that post you mentioned. But it didn't cleared my doubt

Comment: Your doubts do not change the fact that it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The product may be understood geometrically as the *projection* of one vector onto another, multiplied by the length of the vector that it is projected onto. If one takes the dot product of two vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, we can apply this procedure to find the correct formula for the dot product:

Let's call the angle between the vectors $\varphi$. Then, the projection of $\vec{a}$ onto $\vec{b}$ is $|\vec{a}|\cos \varphi$. Multiplying by the length of $\vec{b}$ gives us 
$$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\cos\varphi$$
This is the correct expression for the dot product. Of course, the dot product is symmetric so we might as well picture it as projecting $\vec{b}$ along $\vec{a}$.

Comment: I understand that the multiplication of the projection of $\vec{a}$ onto $\vec{b}$ (|$\vec{a}|cos\theta$) with |$\vec{b}$| gives the dot product of vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. But my doubt is that, what does this quantity represents. Whats the application of it.

Comment: I agree with the OP, the answer does not answer what the scalar represents.